# create a bluemix postgresql service pointing to existing instance

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We have a set of SpringBoot applications being deployed in Bluemix as a service. Each Springboot app will have its own database schema. This is working fine when in the manifest file for each app we mention the  properties

- spring.datasource.url:
- spring.datasource.username:
- spring.datasource.password:
- spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema:

Now we are planning to use cloudfoundry/bluemix services and bind it to the individual app instead of passing the properties. From the bluemix console we can create a Postgresql service, but we don't get the option to point to an existing instance (created in compose) and pass the db credentials.

Can we create a service via CLI where we point it to an existing db instance and provide the credentials? If so how can we do that?

Thanks.
Tatha

Comment: "compose"? What is that and what makes it different from one you create using the Console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a user provided service instance in this case.
For example, create a service instance called `my-postgresqldb` and then bind to your applications:

```
$ cf cups my-postgresqldb -p '{"uri":"http://mydb.net", "port": 2000, "user":"admin", "password":"abcdefg"}'

$ cf bind-service your-application my-postgresqldb
```

Check the `VCAP_SERVICES` for your application in the Bluemix UI and you can see something like this:

```
 "user-provided": [
        {
            "credentials": {
                "password": "abcdefg",
                "port": 2000,
                "uri": "http://mydb.net",
                "user": "admin"
            },
            "syslog_drain_url": "",
            "label": "user-provided",
            "name": "my-postgresqldb",
            "tags": []
        }
    ]
```